# Gtkglextmm and Gtkmm3

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I work on a *Gtkmm-3.0* project and I want to use the openGl Gtk exentsion *Gtkglextmm*. But it seems to me that the actual version of gtkglextmm-1.2 supports only gtkmm-2.x.

Which options I have to use openGl inside gtkmm-3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for Gtkmm 3.18 to be released; the OpenGL widget `Gtk::GLArea` will be built-in to that release. You can see it (and an example of its use) [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/commit/e4f542c84549e28716abd0c89ca2d22a04187938).

Comment: That sounds really nice. At the moment Ubuntu Gnome provides 3.10.1. Du you know how long will it take for the new release?

Comment: I have found, that on [gtkmm.org](http://www.gtkmm.org/de/git.html) rev. 3.17.50 `glarea` already included. But I havn't try it out.
Check it out with git: `git clone git://git.gnome.org/gtkmm`

Comment: Odd-numbered minor versions such as 3.17 are unstable development releases, so that's the version that will eventually become 3.18 when more bugs are fixed.

Comment: That's good to know. But I will try it out and will be aware about the state of this release. For learning it will be enough. The final application will come a few months ago.